# Laravel Mix error when run 'npm run dev'.. Error: Cannot find module './.config/babel.config'

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix, babel-loader

I have a Laravel codebase, and for some reason, I made some modifications to the javascript frontend files (assets), unfortunately, when I try to recompile them using Larvel Mix I get this error shown below:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module './.config/babel.config'
```

Here is the webpackConfig in the wbpack.mix.js file:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let webpack = require('webpack');

let webpackPlugins = [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /moment[\/\\]locale/,
        /(en)\.js/
    )
];

    mix
    
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['jquery', 'moment', 'bootstrap'])
    .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css')
    
    .autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'jquery'],
        moment: 'moment'
    })
    
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: webpackPlugins,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules\/(?!(dom7|swiper)\/).*|bower_components)/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: Config.babel()
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    })
    .options({
        uglify: {
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true,
                    drop_debugger: true
                },
                mangle: true,
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                    beautify: false
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Did you run an initial `npm install` to ensure the package is there? Can you see it in your node_modules folder?

Comment: Yeh, I already run `npm install`.. which package do you mean?